# Is it possible to change the location of the volume overlay?

Tags: windows-8

Windows 8 has a volume overlay feature that I like but the location of it can be annoying:
[image]

Is it possible to change the location of this feature?

Comment: and the brightness too!

Comment: The location is annoying when I use iTunes, because it likes to place itself right over the menu bar. This really should be in the lower left...

Answer (score 2):

At the time of this reply, it is not possible. However, I bet someone will hack it in the future.

Comment: I'm betting this is some registry entry like the Windows 8 snapping feature [that I can't seem to figure out...](http://superuser.com/questions/582157/metro-snapping-on-unsupported-resolution-not-working)